# Using CSS to position text after an image

Tags: css, image, text

I've trying to do something that I'm sure is simple, but I can't do it.

All I want to do is have an image and then some text after that image, and be able to control accurately the amount of space between the image and the text.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="wrap"><div style="width:189px;""position:relative;float:left;top:5px;">
      <a href="http://google.com"><img src="30000000_1.jpg" style="position:absolute" width="189"></a>
</div>
```

In my style sheet, wrap has these attributes:

```
.wrap {
    /*text-align: left;*/
    width: 1100px;
    height: 870px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I want my text to look like this directly below the image:

> Username
>
> Age
>
> Location

Currently, I just add loads of break tags to control where I have the text, but that's messy and there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Make it easier for those want to help by formatting your code, please.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="wrap">
<div style="width:189px;position:relative;float:left;top:5px;">
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="30000000_1.jpg" style="position:absolute" width="189" /></a>
</div>
<br clear="all" />
<div id="bottomText">
Username
<br /><br />
Age
<br /><br />
Location
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    /*text-align: left;*/
    width: 1100px;
    height: 870px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

#bottomText{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Change `margin-top: 10px` to the desired distance.

Change `bottomText` to a class rather than an id, if you plan on having more than one.

(Note: I removed your `""` from the second `div` because I'm not sure why that was there.

Comment: Thanks, I think we're getting there! I can see that the text is there, but it's behind the image...

Comment: @CharlesL Try removing `style="position:absolute"` from the `img` tag

Comment: This, but add a `line-height: 2em;` to `#bottomText{}`, and use a single `<br />` between each of the lines of text. (since these are one-line items)... oh, and the answer was missing a `</div>` after the `<img>` tag (by mistake), which accounts for the weird positioning. I've edited, and it should show up in a moment.

Comment: Here's all my code. http://pastebin.com/2WuKT1VL
And for the syle sheet: http://pastebin.com/nHiadbt6
I've tried doing what you guys have said, but I can't get it to work! Hence showing you all the code as I suspect there's something going on in there that's making your suggestions turn out unexpectedly.

Comment: @CharlesL What problem are you still having?

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gwQA/1/). Personally I will not use inline style, because it becomes more messy. I have used `<ul>` for the text. This can give you better control over the position of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an Unordered List for the text since it is a list. `ul` are "block level elements" so they will self-clear. And definitely use an external stylesheet vs. inline styles. External is much cleaner and easier to work with and make changes to. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/codeview/Fk3EK/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">  
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="30000000_1.jpg"></a>  
<ul>  
<li>Username</li>  
<li>Age</li>  
<li>Location</li>  
<ul>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {  
    /*text-align: left;*/  
    width: 1100px;  
    height: 870px;  
    background-color: yellow;  
    color: black;  
    padding: 10px;  
    margin: auto;  
}  
ul { list-style-type:none; }  
li { padding:5px 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to work. Probably because you guys can't see the other code I have going on. But maybe I was approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Here's my code before I started fiddling with css positioning:

```
<br><br>

 <div class="imgleft">
 <a href="http://image.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a></div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <span style="font-weight: bolder;font-size: 12px;"></br><br><br></br>
    <font color="green">    User69 </font> <a href="google.com"><img src="online01.gif" alt="" border="0" style="float:center"></a><br>

        Location: 
        <script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script> 
        <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region_name());</script></span> 
        </script></br>


<br><br>
```

The problem is, the images have a set width, but vary in height, so sometimes I'll use 8 break tags, other times 7, but the exact distance beneath each image (where the text goes) is different. And it looks bad.

There are 3 images on the page, so it goes image, text (well, there's an image as well, flashing gif) below image, then another image with text below it, and so on. From top to bottom on the left of the page.

Here are the relevant bits from my css:

```
.imgleft {
float: left;
width: 120px;
}

.imgleft img {
clear: both;
width: 175px;
padding-bottom: 0px;

 }
```

I'm certain I'm making this way more complicated than it needs to be! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've put a link to my code in the comments to the first answer, if someone could take a look. Thanks.